# post response is not getting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

html code=>

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/input.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table>
<tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" id="name" ></td></tr>
<tr><td> Address</td><td><input type="text" id="address"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Sex</td><td><input type="radio" name="sex" id="sex" value="male">Male
<input type="radio"  id= "sex"name="sex" value="Female">Female</td></tr>
<tr><td>DOB</td><td><input type="date"  id="dob"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Course</td>
<td><select id="course">
<option value="0">select..</option>
<option value="B.Tech">B.TECH</option>
<option value="MCA">MCA</option>
<option value="MBA">MBA</option>
<option value="BCA">BCA</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>EmailId</td><td><input type="text" id="emailid"></td></tr>
<tr><td>MobileNo</td><td><input type="text" id="mobileno"></td></tr>
 <tr><td colspan="2"> <button id="submit">Submit</button>
 </table>
<form>
</body>
</html>
```

**input.js** => when submit button clicked values are passed to insert .

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#submit').click(function()
    {       
        var name=$("#name").val();
        var address=$("#address").val();
        var gender=$("#sex:checked").val();
        var dob= $("#dob").val();
        var course=$("#course").val();
        var email= $("#emailid").val();
        var mobileno=$("#mobileno").val();
        var data={'name':name,'address':address,'gender':gender,'dob':dob,'course':course,'email':email,'mobileno':mobileno};
        $.post('http://localhost:3111/insert',data,function(result){
           if(result=='success')
           {
             alert("insertion successful");
           }
        });
    });
});
```

**routes.js** => the values are successfully passed here

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db=require('./dbentry.js');

router.post('/insert',function(req,res)
{   
    var name=req.body.name;
    var address=req.body.address;
    var gender=req.body.gender;
    var dob=req.body.dob;
    var course=req.body.course;
    var email=req.body.email;
    var mobileno=req.body.mobileno;
    var insertValues={'name':name,'address':address,'gender':gender,'dob':dob,'course':course,'email':email,'mobileno':mobileno};
    db.insert(insertValues,function(result){
       if(result=="success")
       { 
          res.end("success");  
       }
       else
          res.end("fail");
    });         
});
module.exports = router;
```

**dbentry.js** => function for inserting values

```
var client=require('./dbconnection.js');
function insert(insertValues,callback)
{
    client.connection.query('insert into detail set ?',insertValues,function(err,rows)
    {    
        if(!err)
           callback("success");
        else
           callback("fail");
        }); 
    }
}
module.exports.insert=insert;
```

The values are successfully inserted in database and a success message is passed from `dbentry.js` to `route.js`.
but the problem is from the `route.js` the success message is not passed to the `input.js`.I inspected the code for a long time but I was unable to find the error.

Comment: `console.log(result)` in `input.js` ?

Comment: i have tried that,but it is not coming inside the function. and even i have printed a dummy text inside the function, that too not printed

Comment: Use `res.send()` instead of `res.end()`

Comment: i have tried that too,

Comment: yesterday i did an same kind of code that is working fine, i dont know what is happened here. and i tracked a lot but i can't

Comment: I tried your code, (simulating db part) and its working here.

Comment: so the code is perfect..it might be some other issue.thanks for your valuable reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check your HTML file, if you added "form" tag without onsubmit
and check,submit is happened by  `$('#btnId').click(function(){});`

if it is the case, then remove the unused "form" tag, and check your code is working or not.

i think its happened because of default behavior of form. here the form onSubmit might be empty.